# SQL Distinct - Get all values

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks for looking, I'm trying to get 20 entries from the database randomly and unique, so the same one doesn't appear twice. But I also have a questionGroup field, which should also not appear twice. I want to make that field distinct, but then get the ID of the field selected.

Below is my NOT WORKING script, because it does the ID as distinct too which

```
SELECT DISTINCT `questionGroup`,`id` 
FROM `questions` 
WHERE `area`='1' 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
```

Any advise is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some sample data and a sample result set? It is not clear from the question what exactly are you aiming at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the group by/distinct first in a subquery:

```
select *
from (select distinct `questionGroup`,`id`
      from `questions`
      where `area`='1'
     ) qc
order by rand() 
limit 20
```

I see . . . What you want is to select a random row from each group, and then limit it to 20 groups.  This is a harder problem.  I'm not sure if you can do this accurately with a single query in mysql, not using variables or outside tables.

Here is an approximation:

```
select *
from (select `questionGroup`
             coalesce(max(case when rand()*num < 1 then id end), min(id)) as id
      from `questions` q join
            (select questionGroup, count(*) as num
             from questions
             group by questionGroup
            ) qg
            on qg.questionGroup = q.questionGroup
      where `area`='1'
      group by questionGroup
     ) qc
order by rand() 
limit 20
```

This uses rand() to select an id, taking, on average two per grouping (but it is random, so sometimes 0, 1, 2, etc.).  It chooses the max() of these.  If none appear, then it takes the minimum.

This will be slightly biased away from the maximum id (or minimum, if you switch the min's and max's in the equation).  For most applications, I'm not sure that this bias would make a big difference.  In other databases that support ranking functions, you can solve the problem directly.

Comment: Nice concept but it wouldn't work because your selecting everything from somewhere you've only selected distinct group and id. ID doesnt need to be distinct as it then looks for id and question group distinct which won't work as ID is unique. so i just need distinct question group but want to pull the ID of that result

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
    SELECT `questionGroup`,`id` 
    FROM `questions`
    WHERE `area`='1' 
    ORDER BY rand()
) As q
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: The results I'm looking for would require something like select distinct(`questionGroup`),`id` but unfortunatly you cannot do that as a query :(